# Is there any AI program to auto adjust brightness, contrast, gamma values of camera according to environment lighting? like smartphones do

Tags: camera, brightness, machine-learning

In smartphones, one can see how quickly it identifies faces and adjusts brightness, colour saturation and all other settings. Similarly, I am looking for some applications for Linux. Till now, I found only [DeepCamera](https://github.com/SharpAI/DeepCamera) which is not what I want I guess.

Comment: What is the relation between seeing faces and setting brightness? Phones usually have a light sensor to adjust brightness. As for laptops, most don't have that as far as I know.